# Any stragegies to improve mongodb queries that are slow when using advaced lookups?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've built 3 queries and I am trying to optimize one of them because in my opinion is the best way to do it. Unfortunately, I don't get the performance I expected.

**Fastest query:**
Simple lookups only, but you need to unset a lot of data in the last stage. Imagine having to do that for 20 or 30 fields you do not want. If you use $project you will mess up with the todos collection data, so unset is the only way to do it.

Execution time for my set of data is: **176ms** with my data set offcourse

```
db.todos
    .aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'user_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user',
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$user',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'user_data',
                localField: 'user.data_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user.data',
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$user.data',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
            },
        },
        { $unset: ['user._id', 'user.data_id', 'user.deleted', 'user.active', 'user.data._id'] },
    ])
    .explain();
```

**My Favorite:**
Advanced nested lookups. I like it cause it is clean and clear but I don't think this one uses indexes probably because $expr is used even if it is done on _id.

Execution time for my set of data is: **713ms**

```
db.todos
    .aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                let: { user_id: '$user_id' },
                pipeline: [
                    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$user_id'] } } },
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'user_data',
                            let: { data_id: '$data_id' },
                            pipeline: [
                                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$data_id'] } } },
                                { $project: { _id: 0, name: 1 } },
                            ],
                            as: 'data',
                        },
                    },
                    { $unwind: '$data' },
                    { $project: { _id: 0, email: 1, data: 1 } },
                ],
                as: 'user',
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$user',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
            },
        },
    ])
    .explain();
```

**Worst one:**
Advanced lookups(not nested). Slowest query.
Execution time for my set of data is: **777ms**

```
db.todos
    .aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                let: { user_id: '$user_id' },
                pipeline: [
                    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$user_id'] } } },
                    { $project: { _id: 0, email: 1, data_id: 1 } },
                ],
                as: 'user',
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$user',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'user_data',
                let: { data_id: '$user.data_id' },
                pipeline: [
                    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$data_id'] } } },
                    { $project: { _id: 0, name: 1 } },
                ],
                as: 'user.data',
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$user.data',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
            },
        },
        { $unset: ['user.data_id'] },
    ])
    .explain();
```

I was surprised (being a Mongo beginner) that the way I thought about building queries is not the most effective way. Is there a way to improve the second option or am I stuck with the first one?

A todo

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"612156ec810895cfe9f406bd"},"user_id":{"$oid":"61214827810895cfe9f406ac"},"title":"todo 1"}
```

A user

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"61216d36810895cfe9f40713"},"active":true,"deleted":false,"data_id":{"$oid":"61216d42810895cfe9f40716"},"email":"test2@test2.com"}
```

A user data

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6121488f810895cfe9f406ad"},"name":{"first":"Fanny","last":"Lenny"}}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you built indexs for your $lookup fields?

Comment: Yes, _id by default for all, data_id and user_id where they exist.

Comment: If that's the case, my suggestion is that you may check the query with [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to see if the indexs are utilized(i.e. IXSCAN). After confirming that, you may need to start to check out sharding or reorganizing your data as I don't see much options left with the query tuning itself.

Comment: Thx will do, My guess so far is that either Mongo doesn't use indexes in advanced lookups that use $expr. I hope this is not it as it is kind of a big deal(for me at least)